# PhoneGap 2.30 Exception

Tags: java, android, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm getting an exception for Cordova 2.3.0 in the form of alert that says:

```
Exception Building Cordova JS globals: TypeError: Object.defineProperty called on non-object for key 'device'
```

What does this mean and what is a good way for debugging android devices? There doesn't seem to be a stack trace.

Comment: What is the reproduction scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and its actually really simple, so to save someone else some time in the future, DO NOT name anything in a global scope

```
var device = *variable*;
```

.In 2.30 this will break your app.